# Background Image on Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

The app that i'm building has screens with background images. But i'm facing a lot of problems with the dimensions for each device. I don't know if is a problem with the name convention of the .png files or if i need to do something extra.

Here is my files' names, and the dimensions:

> Default.png (320 x 480), Default@2x.png (640 x 960), Default-568h@2x.png (640 x 1136), Default-667h@2x.png (750 x 1334), Default-736h@3x.png (1242 x 2208)

They're all placed on the resources folder, but i think xamarin is reading only the first file, because it duplicate the image to fit the whole screen, no matter in what device simulator i'm on. Somebody please give me some pointers, because i ran out of ideas.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details. I.e. a screenshot of what is going on. Also details on how you assign this background image.

Answer (score 0):

Added in iOS 7, **Asset Catalogs Image Sets** contain all the versions or representations of an image that are necessary to support various devices and scale factors for an app. Instead of relying on the image assets filename , **Image Sets** use a Json file to specify which image belongs to which device and/or resolution. `This is the preferred way to manage and support images in iOS (from iOS 9 or greater).`

[image]

Details refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=vsmac#adding-images-to-an-asset-catalog-image-set).

Comment: Actually I have a TabbedPage, and all the pages have a background image, so i’m not trying to set a launch screen. In that case, I have to use a Image Set, right?

Comment: Thank you. Those images (1x, 2x, 3x) have any specific dimensions which I have to follow?

Comment: Here is  [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/) for usage.